# inequality $|a-b|^p$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ a nonengative real numbers and $p$ a positive integer  ,I am looking for some inequality like

$$|a-b|^p\leq f(a,b)-g(a,b)$$

where $f$ and $g$ are a positive functions in this form  $f(a,b)=|a|.|b|^q$ and the same for $g(a,b)=|b|.|a|^q$

in other terms i need to see the minus in the upper bound for $|a-b|^p$

Any suggestions or books that brings  this type of inequality is Welcome 
Thank you

Comment: This looks too broad. Take for e.g. $f=LHS+2, g=1$.

Comment: yes you are right i want for example $f(a,b)=|a|.|b|^q$ and the same for $g(a,b)=|b|.|a|^q$    f nd g should be in this type i dont know how to write it if you can edit the question it will be nice thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if $f(a,b)=|a|.|b|^q$ and $g(a,b)=|b|.|a|^q$ then $g(a,b)=f(a,b)$, so if $f(a,b)\ne f(b,a)$ then one of values $f(a,b)-g(a,b)$ and $f(b,a)-g(b,a)$ is negative, so one of inequalities 
$|a-b|^p\le f(a,b)-g(a,b)$ an $|b-a|^p\le f(b,a)-g(b,a)$ fails.

On the other hand, if $a\ge b$ then $(a-b)^p+b^p\le a^p$ because we can place in $p$-dimensional cube with side $a$ non-overlapping $p$-dimensional cubes with sides $a-b$ and $b$.